# jQuery check if input empty (0) on Submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

```
<input type="text" readonly="" value="0" class="input-mini1 sum1"> 
<input type="text" readonly="" value="0" class="input-mini1 sum2">
<input type="text" readonly="" value="0" class="input-mini1 sum3">
<button type="button" id="btn_submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

Solution Tried:

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function(){
    var isFormValid = true;

    $(".input-mini1 input").each(function(){
      if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
         alertify.error("Please check hours");
         isFormValid = false;
      }else{
      alertify.error("Valid hours");
      }
     });

     if (!isFormValid) alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
    return isFormValid;
});
```

For some reason, when I submit the form with empty/zero filled in, it does not validate. User must not submit the form if input value is 0 or 0.0 (either case) and should be validated.

Also when click on submit button, it does not loop through the inputs.

Any ideas how to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector `.input-mini1 input` is wrong, it is looking for `input` elements which are descendants of an element with class `input-mini1`.

it should be `input.input-mini1` since `input-mini1` is the class of the input element

So

```
$("input.input-mini1").each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) {
        alertify.error("Please check timesheet hours");
        isFormValid = false;
    } else {
        alertify.error("Valid timesheet hours");
    }
});
```

Comment: Arun: when click on submit button, it does not loop through the inputs.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yrrhzux5/1/ - it is looping, but you may have to check whether value is 0 also

Comment: Arun: `alertify.error("Please check timesheet hours")`, this alerts number of times the loop goes through

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy then alert it outside of the loop - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yrrhzux5/3/

Comment: Also if one of the input is not null, it still throws exception but should allow to submit. If any one of the inout is not null, user can submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as the class `input-mini1` is attached to your input element itslef.

```
$("input.input-mini1").each(function(){
//    |        |
// " tag . className "
```

`.input-mini1 input` will find children `input` elements of class `input-mini1`

---

For validating `0` value, use Number or parseInt/parseFloat as `.val()` returns a `string`. Your code checks for empty inputs with `length`.

```
if (Number($.trim($(this).val())) == 0){
     alert("Please check timesheet hours");
     isFormValid = false;
  }
```

---

**Final Code**:

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function(){
    var isFormValid = true;

    $("input.input-mini1").each(function(){
      var inpValue = $.trim($(this).val());
      if (!inpValue.length || Number(inpValue) == 0){
          alertify.error("Please check hours");
          isFormValid = false;
      }else{
          alertify.error("Valid hours");
      }
    });

     if (!isFormValid) alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
    return isFormValid;
});
```